# how to separate list to different tables & print the tables to individual pages pdf in reportlab?

Tags: python, list, pdf, reportlab

I have a list of lists

```
data1 = [[('Glass',1.0,'Hardware',900,900,398826),
          ('Mirror',5.0,'Hardware',18000,300,398826),
          ('Plastic',3.0,'Hardware',200,15,398826)],
         [('Metal',1.0,'Hardware',900,900,358947),
          ('Wood',5.0,'Hardware',18000,300,358947)]
        ]
```

and i want to create a different table per list: 1 list into 1 table per page, just like this:
[image]

how do i separate the list into different tables? and have them on different pages using reportlab? assuming that the number of the lists is not always 2 because the data came from a database?

Comment: Your sample indicates that data1 refers to a list of lists where each element is a 6-item tuple. You can iterate over the lists using 'for innerlist in data1' then create your PDF from innerlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `for`-loop to work with every list separatelly

```
for data in data1:
    table = Table(data)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
#from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, PageBreak

all_data = [
    [
        ('Glass',1.0,'Hardware',900,900,398826),
        ('Mirror',5.0,'Hardware',18000,300,398826),
        ('Plastic',3.0,'Hardware',200,15,398826)
    ],
    [
        ('Metal',1.0,'Hardware',900,900,358947),
        ('Wood',5.0,'Hardware',18000,300,358947)
    ]
]

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("output.pdf")

table_style = TableStyle([
        #('BACKGROUND', (1,1), (-2,-2), colors.green),
        #('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (1,-1), colors.red),
        ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.45, colors.black),
        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.blue),
    ])

elements = []

for data in all_data:
    table = Table(data, style=table_style)
    #table.setStyle(table_style)
    elements.append(table)
    elements.append(PageBreak())

# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: I see! i was missing that PageBreak(), thank you!

Comment: if you would show code in question then you would get it without all this example.